# CSS card flip animation goes behind the other card in Safari/Firefox

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions

I have two cards on the screen and when one of them flips, the backside ends up behind the other card in Safari. The same is not true for Chrome. And in Firefox, it temporarily goes behind the other card but then pops forward. Any help would be appreciated!

Drag the card and then, click the black bar to flip it.

Here's the html...

```
<div id="flipStage">
    <div class="card" id="bsg">
        <div class="front" id="bsgFront"></div>
        <div class="back" id="bsgBack" style="color: green;">f</div>
        <div class="flipButton"></div>
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="vger">
        <div class="front" id="vgerFront"></div>
        <div class="back" id="vgerBack" style="color: green;">f</div>
        <div class="flipButton"></div>
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle with CSS and JS that works in Chrome, sorta in Firefox and not in Safari](http://jsfiddle.net/gJaCP/8/)

Answer (score 0):

**z-axis overlap in 3D space**

This is a type of 3D animation. The active card appears larger as if it's physically closer in the 3D space of the animation. Given that the larger card appears to be much closer, you wouldn't expect the smaller card (which appears to be farther away) to overlap with the larger one on the z-axis.

But the z-location of the larger card hasn't actually changed. It's simply been scaled by increasing the width and height properties, to simulate moving it on the z-axis in 3D space. Both cards still occupy the same space on the z-axis. This is why the smaller card appears on top of the larger card at times during the rotation; the browser is rendering two elements that occupy the same space.

**Make the larger card actually be closer in 3D space**

The simplest solution I could quickly toss together was to change the z-location of cards while they're small (when they're supposed to be farther away), so that in the 3D space they actually are farther away.

```
.card.inactive {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -100px);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -100px);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, -100px);
}
```

In the HTML, all cards start with the `.inactive` class, and when a card is brought to the front, the cards are reset so that all cards but the front one have this class. This is a clumsy and somewhat backwards way of doing it, but it should convey the idea.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/RmNcV/2/)